# Angular - как удалить старые данные ng repeat / поменять цвет родителю?

Tags: angularjs

Доброго!

```
<div ng-class="papasha" ng-repeat="i in data" >
    <div ng-repeat="j in datatwo">
        {{i.NAME == j.NAME. ?  j.dats : ""}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том , что `j` у меня динамичен и может быть от `null` до `30` значений. Но `ng repeat` не перезатирает старые данные если `j` не доходит до них. Как решить эту проблему?

Второй вопрос в том, что если `j.dats` у меня отсутствует, то мне надо передать в родителя зелёный бэкграунд иначе красный. Как это можно реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: что значит _передать в родителя_? Что значит _ng repeat не перезатирает старые данные если j не доходит до них_? сделай [mcve] на [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть проблему

Comment: Бред какой-то и ничего не понятно.

Comment: простите нет возможности сделать полноценный пример. Data и Datatwo это json , Data всегда имеет 6 элементов , а Datatwo от ничего до 30 , суть в том , что при обновление страницы создается ng repeat(1) 6 блоков , потом по событию происходит обращение к серверу где возвращается datatwo и ng-repeat(2) должен поместить параметр из него , но к примеру если при первом событии было возвращено 4 элемента , то все ок , а если при втором 2 , то он заменит только верхние 2 и не затрет последующие 2 от предыдущего события.